# how to create two divs which are the same. next to each other and at the same level

Tags: javascript, css

I I want    to create two divs which are the same and next two each other!

But in my code the second div (col2) is next to dov col1 but under it (not at the same level). How can I change that

```
var wrap=document.createElement("div");
        wrap.style.width= '900px';
        wrap.style.margin= '0 auto';
       wrap.style.height= '280px';

        var col1=document.createElement("div");
        col1.style.float= 'left';
        col1.style.width= '450px';
        col1.style.height= '280px';
        col1.style.border= '1px solid';



        var col2=document.createElement("div");
        col2.style.marginLeft ='450px';
        col2.style.width= '450px';
        col2.style.border = '1px solid green';

        var txtNode=document.createTextNode("Item 1 -Hor");

        col2.appendChild(txtNode);

        wrap.appendChild(col1);
                wrap.appendChild(col2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cdbVj/1/

I created a fiddle.

CSS:

```
.first{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px red solid;
    float:left;
}

.second{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;

    margin-left:210px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class ="parent">
        <div class="first">FIRST</div>
        <div class="second">SECOND</div>
    </div>
```

You could post the css accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Reduce width 450px to 448px. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

use both div are floated

```
col2.style.float ='left';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple :
Just create a table with border:0px.
Place the two divs inside a single tr with align left for first div and right for the other.

```
<table style="border: 0px" data-role="content">
  <tr style="border: 0px">
     <td style="border: 0px">
        <div align="left"  data-role="content" style="text-align: center;">
            <div align="left" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                 <p id="id" style="font-size: 22px;"></p>
        </div>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td style="border: 0px">
        <div align="right" data-role="content" style="text-align: center;">
    <button>my button</button>
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```